# CakePHP query for keyword does not return results

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I am building a basic directory for my website. I would like my users to be able to search for entries via three different aspects of the data. A keyword(`$keyword`), state(`$state`), and type of company(`$service_ids`). I can get `$service_ids` and `$state` to return proper results probably since they are drop downs with fixed data. The issue is the `$keyword`. The `$keyword` will return something if you use just one letter. But then it will only return one listing when that letter was probably in almost every listing.

Here is my DirectoryController.php file:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/DirectoryController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;

class DirectoryController extends AppController {

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    global $state_ids;
    if(PREFIX == 'ne') {
        $state_ids = array(
            'CT' => "Connecticut",
            'ME' => "Maine",
            'MA' => "Massachusetts",
            'NH' => "New Hampshire",
            'RI' => "Rhode Island",
            'VT' => "Vermont"
        );
    } else {
        $state_ids = array(
            'UPS' => "Upstate New York",
            'NYC' => "New York City",
            'LI' => "Long Island"
        );
    }
    global $service_ids;
    $service_ids = array( 
        '1'=>"Auctions",
        '2'=>"Brokers",
        '3'=>"Building Services",
        '4'=>"Construction",
        '5'=>"Design Build",
        '6'=>"Economic Development",
        '7'=>"Finance",
        '8'=>"Professional Services",
        '9'=>"Sub Contractors"
    );
}

public function index() {
    $this->load_ads();

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Directory');
    $this->loadModel('Directory');

    $captcha_int = 6;

    if (!empty($this->request->query('keyword')) && $this->request->query('captcha') == $captcha_int) {
        $keyword = $this->request->query('keyword');
    } else {
        $keyword = '';
    }
    $this->set('keyword', $keyword);

    if(is_array($this->request->query('service_ids')) && $this->request->query('captcha') == $captcha_int) {
        //Service array
        $cat_array_services = $this->request->query('service_ids');
        $cat_final_services = implode(',', $cat_array_services);
        $service = $cat_final_services;
        $selected_service_ids = explode(',', $service);
    } else {
        $selected_service_ids = '';
        $service = $this->request->query('service_ids');
    }
    $this->set('selected_service_ids', $selected_service_ids);

    if(is_array($this->request->query('service_ids')) && $this->request->query('captcha') == $captcha_int) {
        //State array
        $cat_array_states = $this->request->query('state_ids');
        $cat_final_states = implode(',', $cat_array_states);
        $state = $cat_final_states;
        $selected_state_ids = explode(',', $state);
        $this->set('selected_state_ids', $selected_state_ids);
    } else {
        $selected_state_ids = '';
        $state = $this->request->query('state_ids');
    }
    $this->set('selected_state_ids', $selected_state_ids);

    $service_ids = $GLOBALS['service_ids'];
    $this->set(compact('service_ids'));

    $services_sidebar = '';
    foreach($service_ids as $key => $value) {
        $count = $this->services_count($key);
        $services_sidebar[] = ['id' => $key, 'title' => $value, 'count' => $count];
    }
    $this->set('services_sidebar', $services_sidebar);

    $state_ids = $GLOBALS['state_ids'];
    $this->set(compact('state_ids'));

    if(empty($service) & empty($state)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            ['Directory.title LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
            ['Directory.body LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
            ['Directory.address LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
            ['Directory.phone LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
            ['Directory.website LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } elseif(empty($keyword) & empty($state)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.service_ids LIKE' => "%".$service."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } elseif(empty($keyword) & empty($service)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.state_ids LIKE' => "%".$state."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } elseif(empty($state)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.title LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.body LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.address LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.phone LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.website LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.service_ids LIKE' => "%".$service."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } elseif(empty($service)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.title LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.body LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.address LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.phone LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.website LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.state_ids LIKE' => "%".$state."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } elseif(empty($keyword)) {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.service_ids LIKE' => "%".$service."%"],
                ['Directory.state_ids LIKE' => "%".$state."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    } else {
        $directory_items = $this->Directory->find('all')->where([
            'OR' => [
                ['Directory.title LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.body LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.address LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.phone LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.website LIKE' => "%".$keyword."%"],
                ['Directory.service_ids LIKE' => "%".$service."%"],
                ['Directory.state_ids LIKE' => "%".$state."%"]
            ]
        ])->order(['logo' => 'DESC']);
    }

    $directory_list = $this->paginate($directory_items);
    $this->set(compact('directory_list'));
}

public function view($slug = NULL) {
    $this->load_ads();
    $this->loadModel('Directory');
    $directory = $this->Directory->find('all')->where(['Directory.slug' => $slug])->first();
    $this->set('title_for_layout', $directory->title);
    if (empty($directory)) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Could not find that directory listing.');
    }
    $this->set('directory', $directory);
    $this->loadModel('Story');
    $directory_stories = $this->Story->find('all')->where(['Story.body LIKE' => '%'.htmlspecialchars($directory->title).'%', 'remove_from_directory' => 0])->limit(5)->order(['id' => 'DESC']);
    $this->set('directory_stories', $directory_stories);
}

public function services_count($service_id) {
    $services = $this->Directory->find('all')->where(['Directory.service_ids LIKE' => '%'.$service_id.'%']);
    $services_count = $services->count();
    return $services_count;
}
```

}

Here is my index.ctp file:

```
<h1 class="page-header">Directory</h1>
<div class="panel panel-default intro_box">
<div class="panel-body">
    Welcome to the Directory.
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8">
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('', array('type' => 'get', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));

echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo $this->Form->input('keyword', array('class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'Please enter a keyword...', 'value' => $keyword));
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo $this->Form->input('service_ids', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'service_ids', 'label' => 'Service', 'empty' => 'Please choose', 'options' => $service_ids));
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo $this->Form->input('state_ids', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'state_ids', 'label' => 'State', 'empty' => 'Please choose', 'options' => $state_ids));
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-md-8">';
echo $this->Form->input('captcha', array('class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'CAPTCHA', 'required' => true));
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
echo '<br /><p>+ 5 = 11</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php
    echo '<div class="list-group">';
    foreach($services_sidebar as $service) {
        echo '<a class="list-group-item" href="'.BASE_URL.'/directory?service_ids='.$service['id'].'">'.$service['title'].' <span class="badge">'.$service['count'].'</span> 
</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($directory_list as $directory_item) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        if(!empty($directory_item->logo)) {
            echo '<a href="'.BASE_URL.'/directory/'.$directory_item->slug.'">';
            echo '<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="'.$directory_item->logo.'"/>';
            echo '</a>';
        }
        $body = substr($directory_item->body,0,50);
        echo '<a href="'.BASE_URL.'/directory/'.$directory_item->slug.'">'.$directory_item- 
>title.'</a>';
        if(!empty($directory_item->address)) {
            echo '<div>' . nl2br($directory_item->address) . '</div>';
        }
        if(!empty($directory_item->address2)) {
            echo '<div>' . nl2br($directory_item->address2) . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div>'.$body.' <a href="'.BASE_URL.'/directory/'.$directory_item->slug.'">Read More... 
</a></div>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<ul class="pagination">
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('prev'), array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','currentTag' => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li','first' => 1));
echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next'), array('tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
?>
</ul>
```

[image: Here is my database structure]

Comment: You should probably clean that conditions up a little, that's quite some duplication there. Check the generated SQL, one of your paths for example doesn't use `OR` for the `LIKE` conditions.

Comment: @ndm That was it, it works! I know, its a bit redundant. Still new to php in general. I will probably invest some more time into my conditions once I learn a bit more. For now I really just wanted it to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the credit of @ndm he noticed I needed to add an `OR` to my fist set of conditions. Happened to be for the `$keyword` variable that wasn't returning any results.